# javascript to get url of previous page

Tags: javascript, back-button

I want to get url of previous page. I found a lot of answers but I couldn't find anything which works with back button of browser. I used 
    document.referrer
but it also doesn't work for back button.
Can anyone help me??

Comment: See the history API.

Comment: i have same issue, i used local storage (or you can use cookie as well) to store previous url.
localStorage.setItem("previourUrl", window.location.href); and get url of previous page by localStorage.getItem("previourUrl");

Hope it will help someone :)

Answer (score 5):

Use the following in javascript snipet

```
document.referrer;
```

if you are implementing back button use this

```
<a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Back</a>
```

Comment: <a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Back</a> This link will redirect me to previous page whereas I need url of previuos page when browser back button is clicked.

Answer (score -2):

you can use `document.referrer`.

in your javascript file, just simply add

```
window.location = document.referrer;
```